# How do I add additional translated items via the MediaWiki Universal Language Selector extension?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, translation

I have added some contents to the MediaWiki sidebar (**MediaWiki:Sidebar**). When I changed the language from English to Malayalam using the Universal Language Selector, everything in the sidebar except the newly added contents got translated.

My questions:

1. What do I do to get all the sidebar contents to be translated to
   Malayalam?
2. Can I add those contents along with the translations to some file in
   the extension's folder so that it also will get translated?

Comment: See [Manual:Interface/Sidebar#Translations](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar#Translations) and [Localised sidebar tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate/Unstructured_element_translation#Localised_sidebar_tutorial) for information about this.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Waldir:

- You should specify the link and the link label as system messages and create language code subpages of said messages for them to follow user interface language. See the [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar#Translations) for more. For instance `* portal-url|portal` with [[MediaWiki:Portal]] being "Portale" and [[MediaWiki:Portal/en]] "Portal" (on an Italian wiki).
- You can also [use the Translate extension to translate the sidebar messages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate/Unstructured_element_translation#Localised_sidebar_tutorial).